# Prime Zeta Function proof help: Why are these expressions not equal?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to create a formula for the Prime Zeta function and I partially succeeded except for one frustrating error. I was only able to formulate an approximation.

Consider the following sum: $$f_k(s)=\sum_{q\space\nmid\space{p_{n\le k}}}^\infty \frac 1{q^s}$$

This is the infinite sum of the reciprocals of all the numbers, raised to the power s, that are not divisible by any primes less than or equal to the *k*th prime.

For example, $f_1(s)=1+\frac 1{3^s}+\frac 1{5^s}+\frac 1{7^s}+\frac 1{9^s}+\frac 1{11^s}+\frac 1{13^s}+\frac 1{15^s}+\cdots$

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ $f_2(s)=1+\frac 1{5^s}+\frac 1{7^s}+\frac 1{11^s}+\frac 1{13^s}+\frac 1{17^s}+\frac 1{19^s}+\frac 1{23^s}+\frac 1{25^s}+\cdots$

By taking $f_k(s)-({p_{k+1}}^{-s})f_k(s)$ we end up with $f_{k+1}(s)$. In other words $$f_k(s)\left(\frac {{p_{k+1}}^s-1}{{p_{k+1}}^s}\right)=f_{k+1}(s)$$

Therefore, since we define $f_0(s)=\zeta(s)$, it's clear that $$f_k(s)=\zeta(s)\left(\prod_{n=1}^k\frac {{p_n}^s-1}{{p_n}^s}\right)$$

It can also be shown that $$f_k(s)=\zeta(s)\left(\frac {P(k,s)^2-P(k,2s)}2-P(k,s)+1\right)$$ where $P(k,s)$ is the partial Prime Zeta Function: $$P(k,s)=\sum_{p\in primes}^k \frac 1{p^s}$$

This is where I hit a snag.  I want to equate the above two equations for $f_k(s)$ like this: $$f_k(s)=\zeta(s)\left(\prod_{n=1}^k\frac {{p_n}^s-1}{{p_n}^s}\right)=\zeta(s)\left(\frac {P(k,s)^2-P(k,2s)}2-P(k,s)+1\right)$$ In theory they should be equal, but when I test them, they show to be slightly different, especially for larger *k*. Why is this? I can't figure out a single reason why they should be unequal.

If they were perfectly equal, then $$P(s)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(1-\sqrt{\frac 2{\zeta(2^0s)}-\sqrt{\frac 2{\zeta(2^1s)}-\sqrt{\frac 2{\zeta(2^2s)}-\cdots-\sqrt{\frac 2{\zeta(2^xs)}-1}}}}\right)$$
However, they are only almost equal and thus this is simply an approximation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "it can also be shown" expression is wrong. It only contains terms with up to two different prime factors. Write it out for $k=3$ to see that it differs from the correct expression by a term $\zeta(s)(2\cdot3\cdot5)^{-s}$.

Comment: I'm sorry @joriki.  I still don't quite see how that expression is wrong.  I can see how it differs there for k=3, but I don't understand the significance in how you said "it only contains terms with up to two different prime factors".  I am aware of this.  I derived it that way.

Comment: Consider you start at $\zeta(s)$ and subtract $(2^{-s})\zeta(s)$ then add $((3*2)^{-s})\zeta(s)$ and subtract $((3)^{-s})\zeta(s)$ then add $((5*2)^{-s})\zeta(s)$, add $((5*3)^{-s})\zeta(s)$, and subtract $((5)^{-s})\zeta(s)$ then add $((7*2)^{-s})\zeta(s)$, add $((7*3)^{-s})\zeta(s)$, add $((7*5)^{-s})\zeta(s)$, and subtract $((7)^{-s})\zeta(s)$ and so on...

This process is defined by the  ""it can also be shown"" expression.  It makes perfect sense to me... @joriki

Comment: @TyO'Brien: You're only considering pairs of primes, but the correct expression rightly contains products for any number of primes, not just pairs. If you subtract for $2$, $3$ and $5$, then add for $2\cdot3$, $2\cdot5$ and $3\cdot5$, you've subtracted the term for $2\cdot3\cdot5$ a net total of $0$ times, where in fact you should be subtracting it once, so you need to subtract it once more. Perhaps looking at [the Wikipedia article on inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) will help to make this clearer.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  But you're not saying that if I were to subtract for $2$, $3$, and $5$ once more, the value will be correct, right?  Because I tried that and I still don't get the right answer.  What, then, would be the right action to take to make the formula correct? @joriki

Comment: @TyO'Brien: I do think that you should get $f_3$ right if you subtract for $2$, $3$ and $5$ once more -- what did you get instead? (BTW, you don't need to ping me under my own answer; that notification is generated automatically.)

Comment: Well to make things simple I don't include the zeta term because that would cancel and say $s=2$.  For $k=3$, the product equals $0.64$.  For the other term without doing the extra subtraction, I get $577/900$ which is pretty close.  With the extra subtraction I get $0.24$.  I probably just don't quite understand yet and so I didn't do it right... Oh... I'll stop XD.  I'm new.

Comment: @TyO'Brien: What are you subtracting? You should be subtracting $2^{-s}\cdot3^{-s}\cdot5^{-s}$, which for $s=2$ is exactly the $1/900$ that you're off by.

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. I know that this works, but what about for a different $k$? Is there a more generalized form to subtract?  For $k=4$ and $s=2$ I have to subtract $86\cdot 2^{-2}\cdot 3^{-2}\cdot 5^{-2}\cdot 7^{-2}$.

Comment: @TyO'Brien: Did you check out the Wikipedia article I linked to above? That gives a systematic treatment of this sort of thing. (Funny enough, I just noticed that it actually has the example "How many integers in {1,...,100} are not divisible by 2, 3 or 5?" :-). If you're still looking for an expression similar to the one you had, I think you'd need terms with $P(k,ns)$ for all $n$ to make it right.